# Python 3 - TypeError: string indices must be integers / conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I thought that so long that the if statement is True, then run the line of code. Why is it wanting an integer in the conditional?

```
#function that accepts a string and calculates the number of upper case and lower case

def case_count(str):
    total_cap_cases = 0
    total_low_cases = 0
    for words in str:
        if str[words].isupper():
            total_cap_cases += 1
        elif words.islower():
            total_low_cases += 1
        else:
            pass

    print(total_cap_cases)
    print(total_low_cases)


str = "How Many upper and LOWER case lettters are in THIS senTence?"
case_count(str)
```

Comment: Do not use 'str' as variable's name, it's Python keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run this code:

```
s = "abc"

for words in s:
    print(words)
```

I get this output:

```
$ python test.py
a
b
c
```

This is because `for variable in string:` does not create an integer index. Rather, it assigns the individual *characters* of the string to `variable,` one at a time.

When you do `for words in str:`, you are actually processing the `str` one character at a time. You would do better to write:

```
for character in str:
    if character.isupper():
        tot_cap_cases += 1
    elif character.islower():
        tot_low_cases += 1
    else:
        tot_non_cases += 1
```

(Also, it's worth pointing out that in the world of unicode, you cannot simply assume that any character that is not upper case must be lower case. According to [this Unicode FAQ page](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html) most scripts do not have case at all.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is more clear than reading the documentation xP

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use a `str` to index, but it should be of type `int`.

To fix it, you can simply change:

```
if str[words].isupper():
```

to:

```
if words.isupper():
```

I also recommend using `replace(' ', '')` on your `str`, as the spaces might count when computing the values.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code. You should just use words.isupper(): instead of str[words].isupper()

```
def case_count(str): 
    total_cap_cases = 0 
    total_low_cases = 0 
    for words in str: 
        if words.isupper(): 
            total_cap_cases += 1 
        else: 
            total_low_cases += 1
    print(total_cap_cases)
    print(total_low_cases)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate string in python, but string isn't list. 
it indices must be integers, not str

```
def case_count(string):
    total_cap_cases = 0
    total_low_cases = 0
    for words in string:
        if words.isupper():
            total_cap_cases += 1
        else:
            total_low_cases += 1

    print(total_cap_cases)
    print(total_low_cases)
```

OR

```
def case_count(string):
    total_cap_cases = 0
    total_low_cases = 0
    for idx in range(0, len(string)):
        if string[idx].isupper():
            total_cap_cases += 1
        else:
            total_low_cases += 1

    print(total_cap_cases)
    print(total_low_cases)
```

plus, do not use `str` as variable. it's python keyword.

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "How Many upper and LOWER case lettters are in THIS senTence?"

def case_Counts(String):
print("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for String in str if String.isupper()))
print("LowerCase Letters: ", sum(1 for String in str if String.islower()))

case_Counts(str)
```